# jQuery UI Selectable : How to get marching ants style lasso to show up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selectable

I've just started injection some jquery UI goodness into my app and am struggling with a rather minor issue. I have the selectable plugin working but I can seem to get the lasso marquee box thing to show up when dragging to select multiple.

**Working Example on jquery UI site:** http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#default

**My Attempt:** http://jsbin.com/amare5/2/edit

The code used is an exact copy of the example of the jquery UI site. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the jQuery UI CSS file. Try this: http://jsbin.com/amare5/4. I added this to the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
```

Comment: WORKED! Without havving to import the whole style sheet I just needed this line: .ui-selectable-helper { position: absolute; z-index: 100; border:1px dotted black; }

Answer (score 10):

**WORKED! Thank you @mattball!** Without having to import the whole style sheet you just need this chunk:

```
.ui-selectable-helper{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  border:1px dotted black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking for the ui-selectable-helper class definition, you can simply import the selectable CSS.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/selectable.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to bring the selector on top of the dialog windows, define this somewhere in your stylesheet:

```
.ui-selectable-helper{
    z-index: 101; /* 101 or more */
}
```